# Missing 'options' attribute in the diffgram. Microsoft DiffAndPatch GUI tool

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the microsoft diff and patch gui tool. While executing the statement dv.load i Get an error: [missing options attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwEGw.png)

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in XmlDiffPatch.View.dll

> Additional information: Missing 'options' attribute in the diffgram.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.XmlDiffPatch;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string oldxml = "<form><tabs><tab name=\"general\" verticallayout=\"true\" id=\"{5eb9e7cf-effa-4732-bfeb-d482b5652520}\" IsUserDefined=\"0\"><columns><column width=\"25%\"><sections><section name=\"ColorStrip\" showlabel=\"false\" showbar=\"false\" columns=\"1\" IsUserDefined=\"0\" id=\"{7fdcb32a-3e98-40ab-aeda-cf521f77c2de}\"></section></sections></column><column width=\"75%\"><sections><section name=\"CardHeader\" showlabel=\"false\" showbar=\"false\" columns=\"111\" id=\"{0ff9556b-e42d-4cd4-829c-d8e6113a5064}\" IsUserDefined=\"0\"><rows><row><cell id=\"{2506b8ee-4e32-424c-a032-7c9b95d70721}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"><control id=\"statuscode\" classid=\"{5D68B988-0661-4db2-BC3E-17598AD3BE6C}\" datafieldname=\"statuscode\" disabled=\"false\" /></cell><cell id=\"{c86dbf55-72ee-4ff8-8d57-5ca6377bc397}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"></cell><cell id=\"{984dd953-3556-4de4-9505-40fd1358007e}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"></cell></row></rows></section><section name=\"CardDetails\" showlabel=\"false\" showbar=\"false\" columns=\"1\" id=\"{100e61a9-6a57-4f32-9385-214d88dcc782}\" IsUserDefined=\"0\"><rows><row><cell id=\"{848b1cf6-075c-4dc7-b6d8-e1bf5e8be223}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"><control id=\"new_name\" classid=\"{4273EDBD-AC1D-40d3-9FB2-095C621B552D}\" datafieldname=\"new_name\" disabled=\"false\" /></cell></row></rows></section><section name=\"CardFooter\" showlabel=\"false\" columns=\"1111\" showbar=\"false\" id=\"{52ff4be4-8e82-47f8-9fee-0148c7807eeb}\" IsUserDefined=\"0\"><rows><row><cell id=\"{81f56aad-9280-40ff-988a-77788ec5d9c6}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"><control id=\"ownerid\" classid=\"{270BD3DB-D9AF-4782-9025-509E298DEC0A}\" datafieldname=\"ownerid\" disabled=\"false\" /></cell><cell id=\"{4b0c5a03-c268-4da4-88fa-9651543454f1}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"><control id=\"createdon\" classid=\"{270BD3DB-D9AF-4782-9025-509E298DEC0A}\" datafieldname=\"createdon\" disabled=\"false\" /></cell><cell id=\"{46d0c273-fd3c-4e31-a790-40ae6fe58af0}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"></cell><cell id=\"{ed31d13f-f917-4cdd-827f-425aa481ea00}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"></cell></row></rows></section></sections></column></columns></tab></tabs></form>";
        string newxml = "<form><tabs><tab name=\"general\" verticallayout=\"true\" id=\"{5eb9e7cf-effa-4732-bfeb-d482b5652520}\" IsUserDefined=\"0\"><columns><column width=\"25%\"><sections><section name=\"ColorStrip\" showlabel=\"false\" showbar=\"false\" columns=\"1\" IsUserDefined=\"0\" id=\"{7fdcb32a-3e98-40ab-aeda-cf521f77c2de}\"></section></sections></column><column width=\"75%\"><sections><section name=\"CardHeader\" showlabel=\"false\" showbar=\"false\" columns=\"111\" id=\"{0ff9556b-e42d-4cd4-829c-d8e6113a5064}\" IsUserDefined=\"0\"><rows><row><cell id=\"{2506b8ee-4e32-424c-a032-7c9b95d70721}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"><control id=\"statuscode\" classid=\"{5D68B988-0661-4db2-BC3E-17598AD3BE6C}\" datafieldname=\"statuscode\" disabled=\"false\" /></cell><cell id=\"{c86dbf55-72ee-4ff8-8d57-5ca6377bc397}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"></cell><cell id=\"{984dd953-3556-4de4-9505-40fd1358007e}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"></cell></row></rows></section><section name=\"CardDetails\" showlabel=\"false\" showbar=\"false\" columns=\"1\" id=\"{100e61a9-6a57-4f32-9385-214d88dcc782}\" IsUserDefined=\"0\"><rows><row><cell id=\"{848b1cf6-075c-4dc7-b6d8-e1bf5e8be223}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"><control id=\"new_name\" classid=\"{4273EDBD-AC1D-40d3-9FB2-095C621B552D}\" datafieldname=\"new_name\" disabled=\"false\" /></cell></row></rows></section><section name=\"CardFooter\" showlabel=\"false\" columns=\"1111\" showbar=\"false\" id=\"{52ff4be4-8e82-47f8-9fee-0148c7807eeb}\" IsUserDefined=\"0\"><rows><row><cell id=\"{81f56aad-9280-40ff-988a-77788ec5d9c6}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"><control id=\"ownerid\" classid=\"{270BD3DB-D9AF-4782-9025-509E298DEC0A}\" datafieldname=\"ownerid\" disabled=\"false\" /></cell><cell id=\"{4b0c5a03-c268-4da4-88fa-9651543454f1}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"><control id=\"createdon\" classid=\"{270BD3DB-D9AF-4782-9025-509E298DEC0A}\" datafieldname=\"createdon\" disabled=\"false\" /></cell><cell id=\"{46d0c273-fd3c-4e31-a790-40ae6fe58af0}\" showlabel=\"true\" locklevel=\"0\"></cell></row></rows></section></sections></column></columns></tab></tabs></form>";

        List<char> list1 = new List<char>();
        List<char> list2 = new List<char>();

        XmlDiff diff = new XmlDiff();
        XmlDiffOptions diffOptions = new XmlDiffOptions();

        diffOptions = XmlDiffOptions.None;


        //Read the options settings and OR the XmlDiffOptions enumeration.
        diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePI;

        diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder;

        diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreComments;

        diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreDtd;

        diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces;

        diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes;

        diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreWhitespace;

        diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreXmlDecl;

        diff.Algorithm = XmlDiffAlgorithm.Auto;

        diff.Options = diffOptions;

        for (int i = 0; i < oldxml.Length; i++)
        {
            if (oldxml[i] == '\\' && oldxml[i] == '\"')
            {
                list1.Add('"');
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                list1.Add(oldxml[i]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < newxml.Length; i++)
        {
            if (newxml[i] == '\\' && newxml[i] == '\"')
            {
                list2.Add('"');
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                list2.Add(newxml[i]);
            }
        }

        string xml1 = string.Join("", list1.ToArray());
        string xml2 = string.Join("", list2.ToArray());


        XmlReader node1 = XElement.Parse(xml1).CreateReader();
        XmlReader node2 = XElement.Parse(xml2).CreateReader();
        bool compareFragments = true;

        var result = new XDocument();
        var writer = result.CreateWriter();

        bool isEqual = false;
        try
        {
            isEqual = diff.Compare(node1, node2, writer);
        }
        catch (XmlException xe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An exception occured while comparing\n" + xe.StackTrace);
        }


        writer.Flush(); writer.Close();

        if (isEqual)
        {
            //This means the files were identical for given options.
            Console.Write("Files Identical for the given options");
            return; //dont need to show the differences.
        }
        XmlDiffView dv = new XmlDiffView();

        XmlTextReader old = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xml1));
        old.Read();

        XmlTextReader dif = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xml2));
        dif.Read();

        //Load the original file again and the diff file.
        dv.Load(old,dif);

        //Wrap the HTML file with necessary html and 
        //body tags and prepare it before passing it to the GetHtml method.

        string tempFile = "abc.htm";
        StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(tempFile);


        sw1.Write("<html><body><table width='100%'>");
        //Write Legend.
        sw1.Write("<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><b>Legend:</b> <font style='background-color: yellow'" +
            " color='black'>added</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style='background-color: red'" +
            " color='black'>removed</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style='background-color: " +
            "lightgreen' color='black'>changed</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
            "<font style='background-color: red' color='blue'>moved from</font>" +
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style='background-color: yellow' color='blue'>moved to" +
            "</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style='background-color: white' color='#AAAAAA'>" +
            "ignored</font></td></tr>");


        sw1.Write("<tr><td><b> File Name : ");
        sw1.Write("1");
        sw1.Write("</b></td><td><b> File Name : ");
        sw1.Write("2");
        sw1.Write("</b></td></tr>");

        //This gets the differences but just has the 
        //rows and columns of an HTML table
        dv.GetHtml(sw1);

        //Finish wrapping up the generated HTML and complete the file.
        sw1.Write("</table></body></html>");

        //HouseKeeping...close everything we dont want to lock.
        sw1.Close();
        dv = null;
        old.Close();
        dif.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your options to the  `XmlDiff`  constructor:

```
XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder | 
                                XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces | 
                                XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
```

So rearrange your code like this:

```
    XmlDiffOptions diffOptions = new XmlDiffOptions();

    diffOptions = XmlDiffOptions.None;

    //Read the options settings and OR the XmlDiffOptions enumeration.
    diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePI;

    diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder;

    diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreComments;

    diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreDtd;

    diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces;

    diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes;

    diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreWhitespace;

    diffOptions = diffOptions | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreXmlDecl;

    diff.Algorithm = XmlDiffAlgorithm.Auto;

    XmlDiff diff = new XmlDiff(diffOptions);
```